# Halide/Hexagon support on Linux

Tags: halide, qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

Is Halide's Hexagon targeting supported on 820E Linux platforms?

The Github project says:

> The currently supported combination of targets is to use the HVX target features with an x86 linux host (to use the simulator) or with an ARM android target (to use Hexagon DSP hardware).

Is targeting Linaro / Linux also supported, as well as Android?

Answer (score 3):

There's no major technical reason that I'm aware of that it shouldn't be supportable on Linaro/Linux (vs Android); however, you'd probably need to update the Halide runtime code as needed to support hvx operations on Linux (vs Android) -- e.g. loading and calling code, code signing issues, etc. I don't know of any reason the Halide maintainers wouldn't welcome. (It's probably worth asking about this on the Halide mailing list and/or Gitter channel, where various Qualcomm folk could probably shed more light on what's needed.)